# How to use css clip-path in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am facing an issue to render this style in React 
`style="clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%)"` 
I tried to write as `style={{ clipPath: polygon("10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%") }}`
but Iget polygone is not defined

Answer (score 4):

Surround the value of `clipPath` with quotes and remove the inner quotes

```
style={{ clipPath: 'polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%)' }}
```

Full example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/w3css.gif"
        alt="logo"
        style={{
          clipPath: "polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%)"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by writing the following code `` style={{clipPath: `polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%)`}} ``